# Hive partition not being done

Tags: hive

iam trying to do a simple hive partition based on country, creating table, loading data is perfect but partitioning is not being done. Based on country I am trying to do partition but after executing the hive query total document data is being displayed. can anyone helpmeout

Comment: Pls share qry etc.and error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The below are the commands i used.
create table ritvik(id int,name string,salary int)
    partitioned by (country string,state string)
    row format delimited fields terminated by ' '
    lines terminated by '\n'
    stored as textfile;

load data local inpath '/home/sbkt/Desktop/hive-programs/empap' into table ritvik
     partition (country='in', state='ap');

Answer (score 0):

If what you meant is to have a table with country as a partition, then this might help

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (city string, address string) partitioned by (country string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

Comment: I have done, Creating table as mentioned , I didnt find any errors there. Loading data is also being done. But if I try to look into the data after loading into partitioned table, it is not getting partitioned.

Comment: you need to load the data with partition as well so that your data in the table will be partitioned.

Comment: create table ritvik(id int,name string,salary int) partitioned by (country string,state string) row format delimited fields terminated by ' ' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile; 
load data local inpath '/home/sbkt/Desktop/hive-programs/empap' into table ritvik partition (country='in', state='ap');

Please check and let me know the fault